# How to return 400 (Bad Request) on Flask?

Tags: python, http, flask, bad-request

I have created a simple flask app that and I'm reading the response from python as:

```
response = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers ) 
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Now my issue is that under certain conditions I want to return a 400 or 500 message response. So far I'm doing it like this:

```
abort(400, 'Record not found') 
#or 
abort(500, 'Some error...')
```

This does print the message on the terminal:

[image]

But in the API response I kept getting a 500 error response:

[image]

The structure of the code is as follows:

```
|--my_app
   |--server.py
   |--main.py
   |--swagger.yml
```

Where `server.py` has this code:

```
from flask import render_template
import connexion
# Create the application instance
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="./")
# read the swagger.yml file to configure the endpoints
app.add_api("swagger.yml")
# Create a URL route in our application for "/"
@app.route("/")
def home():
    """
    This function just responds to the browser URL
    localhost:5000/

    :return:        the rendered template "home.html"
    """
    return render_template("home.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="33")
```

And `main.py` has all the function I'm using for the API endpoints.

E.G:

```
def my_funct():
   abort(400, 'Record not found')
```

When `my_funct` is called, I get the `Record not found` printed on the terminal, but not in the response from the API itself, where I always get the 500 message error.

Comment: Show the full code for the route-- with the little you have currently shared, I can't tell if you're not `return`ing the abort, or if you've got another logic error.

Comment: For what it's worth, 404 is the canonical code for "record not found". See [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: @Doobeh I just updated the question

Answer (score 135):

You have a variety of options:

The most basic:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Record not found", 400
```

If you want to access the headers, you can grab the response object:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    resp = make_response("Record not found", 400)
    resp.headers['X-Something'] = 'A value'
    return resp
```

Or you can make it more explicit, and not just return a number, but return a status code object

```
from flask_api import status

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Record not found", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

#### Further reading:

You can read more about the first two here: [About Responses](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses) (Flask quickstart)
And the third here: [Status codes](https://flask-api.github.io/flask-api/api-guide/status-codes/) (Flask API Guide)

Answer (score 40):

I like to use the `flask.Response` class:

```py
from flask import Response


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return Response(
        "The response body goes here",
        status=400,
    )
```

`flask.abort` is a wrapper around `werkzeug.exceptions.abort` which is really just a [helper method](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/exceptions/#simple-aborting) to make it easier to raise HTTP exceptions. That's fine in most cases, but for restful APIs, I think it may be better to be explicit with return responses.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on what the Response class adds over reutrning just a tuple of str/code?

Comment: @AdamHughes in this instance they are identical, as in Flask is calling Response when you pass it the tuple. Response also allows you to set content type and mime type but I believe you can do this without importing response. Miguel Grinberg has [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/customizing-the-flask-response-class) to say.

Comment: @AdamHughes Self-describing code. Personally I find it much more explicit to say "here is a response, with this text, and this status" than just returning a bare string and a magic number. One doesn't have to know the Flask API to understand what this does; it's instantly obvious. (Anyone familiar with HTTP will recognise the 400 status with a Bad Request text as well, but it's a more general principle than just this particular number.)

Answer (score 7):

You can return a tuple with the second element being the status (either 400 or 500).

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Record not found", 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Example of calling the API from python:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

response.text
# 'This is a bad request!'

response.status_code
# 400
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's some snippets from a Flask app I wrote years ago. It has an example of a 400 response

```
import werkzeug
from flask import Flask, Response, json
from flask_restplus import reqparse, Api, Resource, abort
from flask_restful import request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('address_to_score', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')

class MissingColumnException(Exception):
    pass

class InvalidDateFormatException(Exception):
    pass

@api.route('/project')
class Project(Resource):

    @api.expect(parser)
    @api.response(200, 'Success')
    @api.response(400, 'Validation Error')
    def post(self):
        """
        Takes in an excel file of addresses and outputs a JSON with scores and rankings.
        """
        try:
            df, input_trees, needed_zones = data.parse_incoming_file(request)

        except MissingColumnException as e:
            abort(400, 'Excel File Missing Mandatory Column(s):', columns=str(e))

        except Exception as e:
            abort(400, str(e))

        project_trees = data.load_needed_trees(needed_zones, settings['directories']['current_tree_folder'])

        df = data.multiprocess_query(df, input_trees, project_trees)
        df = data.score_locations(df)
        df = data.rank_locations(df)
        df = data.replace_null(df)
        output_file = df.to_dict('index')
        resp = Response(json.dumps(output_file), mimetype='application/json')
        resp.status_code = 200

    return resp

@api.route('/project/health')
class ProjectHealth(Resource):

    @api.response(200, 'Success')
    def get(self):
        """
        Returns the status of the server if it's still running.
        """
        resp = Response(json.dumps('OK'), mimetype='application/json')
        resp.status_code = 200

    return resp
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're using the `abort()` function correctly.  I suspect the issue here is that an error handler is that is catching the 400 error and then erroring out which causes the 500 error.  See [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/errorhandling/) for more info on flask error handling.

As an example, the following would change a 400 into a 500 error:

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def handle_400_error(e):
    raise Exception("Unhandled Exception")
```

If you're not doing any error handling, it could be coming from the `connexion` framework, although I'm not familiar with this framework.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `@app.errorhandler` decorator.

example:

```
 @app.errorhandler(400)
    def your_function():
        return 'your custom text', 400
```

Answer (score 1):

Raise an exception and let the default error handler deal with it. See:

- [HTTP Exceptions](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound)
- [Error handling](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/errorhandling/)

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound


@bp.get('/account/<int:account_id>')
def show(account_id):
    if None:
        raise NotFound()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
import cv2
from learn import text_detection

app = Flask(name)

BASE_PATH = os.getcwd()
UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH,'static/upload')

print(UPLOAD_PATH)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST": #Получие картинок из input  в путь UPLOAD_PATH
        upload_file = request.files['file']
        filename = upload_file.filename
        path_save = os.path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, filename)
        upload_file.save(path_save)
        
        text = text_detection(path_save, filename)
        
        return render_template('other.html', upload=True, upload_image = filename, text=text, )
    
    return render_template('other.html',upload=False)

if name == "main":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?